# BEMの公式サイトらしきものが2つある

Tags: css

BEMの公式サイトらしきものが2つあるような気がします

- getbem.com [BEM — Block Element Modifier](http://getbem.com/)

  - 「BEM」で検索するとこちらが私の場合は上位にきている
  - [getbem/getbem.com: Get BEM to all people in simplest way](https://github.com/getbem/getbem.com) GitHubのスターも多い
- en.bem.info [BEM](https://en.bem.info/)

  - ドキュメントが多い

どっちが公式資料なんでしょうか？

Comment: 今回のような場合は何らかの形でドメイン名が分かるような記述にしておくと、ひと目で違いが分かりやすくなるんじゃないかなとも思いました。(リンクテキストがどちらも同じだと、カーソルを重ねるか実際にリンクをクリックするまで分からない)

Comment: 分かるように修正してみました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS BEM, which chars for the modifier..? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806601/css-bem-which-chars-for-the-modifier)

> BEM started as an informal set of guidelines by Yandex, which they later formalized on en.bem.info, so in that regard en.bem.info is the "canonical" version of BEM.

によると、en.bem.info [BEM](https://en.bem.info/)が公式資料のようです。

「Yandexによって非公式に始まりましたが、後に en.bem.info上で正式化された」とあります。